# Best practices for discarding no longer needed objects in memory managed languages

Tags: oop, memory-management

Lets say we have a top level object, in a game for example that represents some physical thing in the game world. The top level object then owns several sub-objects, like a bounding box, graphical object, ect. By own I mean that when it dies so should it's sub-objects.

Lets also say there is a graphical manager object that keeps track of all existing graphical objects in order to draw them or something.

Now lets say that top level object leaves the game world, it's destroyed or we load another level, whatever. We can at this point remove it's reference and it will be GCed, however the graphical object it owns still has a reference to it in the graphical manager. So there needs to be some mechanism of informing the graphical manager to remove it's reference to the graphical object. It's this mechanism that I'm asking about.

The best way I can think of is that every object needs a public `alive` Boolean flag and any other object that doesn't own it but interacts with it and may need to keep a reference to it then needs logic to check for that flag and remove it's references if it's false. But this to me seems like a fairly inelegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You idea is not only inelegant; it is also the not *good OOP*. The *last* thing you want to do is to **expose** a field of a class; and have **outside** classes depend on the content of that field.

That is a direct violation of the [Tell Don't Ask](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html) principle. *State* should be internal; you do not *expose* - especially not for the purpose of **other** objects making decisions based on this state. And of course: most languages do not allow you to synchronize on a **field** - meaning that this approach scream **race conditions** all over the place (when different threads are reading/writing to that field). You can mitigate this by making the field *volatile* (if your language allows for that).

One alternative approach would be to look into the [observer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) pattern. Meaning: the graphical manager registers itself as listener; for example on a central "game manager" - that one component that is actually responsible for adding/removing your game objects. And each time the game manager adds/removes an object, the graphical manager gets notified and can adapt its data structures.

Comment: I disagree about the first bit. Objects need to interact to make a coherent program and in order to interact in meaningful way they need to know information about each other.   The part about the observer pattern does seem like a viable solution.

Comment: Sure, one always has to balance. When you follow my link to read what Martin Fowler has to say you will see that he simply states he doesn't use that principle. The key aspect is that you want to avoid writing **procedural** code. Where you (have to) collect 5 different states from 5 different places to then make a decision on that; possibly affecting the *source* of that state.